# filtering out rows of data based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that includes multiple columns, 2 of which are called chain and sbt. I would like to remove rows from the data frame when chain = Target and sbt = no. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)

table%>%filter(!(sbt == "no" & chain == "Target"))
```

For the next time, do some more research online first:
https://blog.exploratory.io/filter-data-with-dplyr-76cf5f1a258e

Comment: I don't want to filter on just Target though, I want to keep the other chains in the data frame

Comment: this is why you use != instead of ==

Comment: Also, there are other chains in the data frame where sbt will be yes and no. Doing what you suggested gets rid of all of the no's regardless of the chain

Comment: I cant understand what you mean. Can you be more specific about your desired output?

Comment: I have a large data frame with a column that has several chains in it (amz, wmt, target). I also have a dichotomous variable called sbt where there will be either yes or no for each chain. I want to remove the rows from the data frame where chain = Target and sbt = No. I want to keep everything else the same with the data frame.